# Shell script to change var in file before compressing?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm compressing a JS file for production, hoping to automate a bit of tedium required before compressing; the first line of which:

`var deploy = false, test_ads_dev = false, show_interstitial = false,`

I need `var deploy = false` changed to `var deploy = true`, in the file: `app/assets/game.js` (as in the compressor command).

How can I get the script to perform the subsitution?

```
#!/bin/bash
first="var deploy = false"
second="var deploy = true"
first=${first/$second}
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -v -o game.min.js app/assets/game.js
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: I need `var deploy = false` changed to `var deploy = true`. Thanks.

Comment: I would think a little sed command, maybe using the "in-place" editing option, would allow for what you are looking for.

Comment: @tidelake: On a file?

Comment: yes: app/assets/game.js

Answer (score 1):

Just use a minimal `sed` for this below to do the replacement in-place.

```
sed -i.bak 's/\<var deploy = false\>/var deploy = true/' app/assets/game.js
```

`bash` is not really the right tool to do pattern search/replacement on text files, whereas `sed` or `awk` would be.

Comment: that isn't working, still shows `var deploy = false`

Comment: @tidelake: Your previous comment is offensive, as people don;t post answers without testing it, It worked perfectly fine for me

Comment: Is there something to the `-i.bak` I'm possibly missing?

Comment: I had to remove the quotes "<>" from the second part of your `sed` sentence to get it work properly, if I keep the quotes then the output would include them. So, finally this command works: `sed -i.bak 's/\<var deploy = false\>/var deploy = true/' app/assets/game.js`

Comment: @tidelake: Can you remove your rude comment? for whatever you meant it to be

Comment: @tidelake: Go though this http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior and make this community a clean place for programmers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I got the other 60% of the answer by myself.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i.bak 's/var deploy = false/var deploy = true/' app/assets/game.js
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -v -o game.min.js app/assets/game.js
mv app/assets/game.js.bak app/assets/game.js
```

Comment: This can be improved by quoting the first part of the `sed`, so that it will replace an exact match of "var deploy = false". If you don't want to have the original file changed, remove `-i` and direct the output to another file.